# Phonegap android project works on emulator and in some devices but not in a 2.2 android device

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Im making a phonegap application (phonegap 2.9 + jquery 1.8.3 + jquery mobile 1.3.1)
It works perfectly in:
-4.3 android device.
-4.0 android device.
-2.2 android **virtual** device.

The problem is that im having some issues when I install it in an android 2.2.2 device. Some of the api calls work and others dont.

For example, this call works:

```
$.ajax({
    data:   {museum_id:'1'},
    url:    url+'index.php?r=api/ListAllCuriosities',
    type:   'get',
    success:  function (response) {
        var resultado = response['data'];
        var listadohtml = '';
        for (var i=0;i<resultado.length;i++){
            listadohtml += '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" class="titulos"><li>'+resultado[i]['title']+'</li></ul>'
                        +'  <p>'+ resultado[i]['description']+'</p>';
        }

        $('#listCuriosities').html(listadohtml);
        $('#listCuriosities').trigger('create');
    },
    error: function() {
        //something went wrong, handle the error and display a message
        alert('Se ha producido un error en la llamada al servidor');
    }
});
```

But this other doesn't

```
$.ajax({
    data:   {museum_id:'1'},
    url:    url+'index.php?r=api/ListMasterpieces',
    type:   'get',
    success:  function (response) {
        var visitedList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("visited"));
        var resultado = response['data'];
        var listadohtml = '<div>';
        var author = '';


        for (var i=0;i<resultado.length;i++){
            var item = '';
            var isVisited = 'data-theme="a"';

            if(visitedList!=null && resultado[i]['id'] in visitedList && visitedList[resultado[i]['id']]==1){
                isVisited = 'data-theme="b" data-icon="check"';
            }

            if(resultado[i]['authorname']!=author){ // en caso de que el autor haya cambiado se insertará una nueva línea
                item += '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b"><li>'+resultado[i]['authorname']+'</li></ul>';
                author = resultado[i]['authorname'];
            }
            var id = resultado[i]['id'];
            item += '<p><a href="detalle.html?id='+id+'" id="enlace-'+id+'" data-role="button" data-ajax="false" data-prefetch="false" '+isVisited+'>'+resultado[i]["name"] + '</a></p>';

            listadohtml += item;
        }
        listadohtml += '</div>';


        $('#listaMasterpieces').html(listadohtml);
        $('#listaMasterpieces').trigger('create');
    },
    error: function() {
        //something went wrong, handle the error and display a message
        alert('Se ha producido un error en la llamada al servidor');
    }
});
```

I think it can be:
-Because of a a permissions problem (As you can see I store some information in the device)
-Because the jquery doesnt work properly (i dont see the alert of the error ajax-method)

I attach my manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.museum.prado.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks to me like a localStorage problem. Can you verify if you can access your localStorage on the device with 2.2?

Comment: Thanks very much!!! You have show me what was the problem. I could accesed the content but if I have no content it gives me an error (but not with android 4 devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Raoul George i discovered what was the problem.

When you make:

```
var visitedList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("visited"));
```

in an android 4 nothing happens, but if you work with an android 2.2 you need to be sure that window.localStorage.getItem("visited") has a value.